# Treemap visualization in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, treemap

Is there a way to create this type of graph/chart in PowerBI? I can do a treemap but i'd like it to be in this graphic style.
[image]

Comment: another good visual to use would be the infographic designer https://pbivisuals.com/2021/01/16/infographic-designer-custom-visual/

Comment: @Jon I tried that before but could not make an "aggregate" waffle chart, only bar and line charts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but  you will need to use Charticulator or Deneb visuals. Here is an example in Vega-Lite which you can customise and reuse within Deneb. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/isotype_grid.html. Be warned that if you are new to these visuals, there is a bit of a learning curve.

[image]